# Stop clock on pause button

Tags: actionscript-3, timer

I have a "clock" counting down the time of the game (from 9 seconds to 0 seconds). I have a button that pauses the game, so I want to freeze de clock and when I click to play, the game continuos from that second that I frozen. But I don't have any idea how to do this! Can you help me please?

```
this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, updateTimer);

    function updateTimer(e:Event){
        var t:uint = getTimer();
    var dt:uint = 9000 - t;
    var totseconds:uint = Math.floor(dt/1000);
    var minutes:uint = Math.floor(totseconds/60);
    var seconds:uint = Math.floor(totseconds%60);
    var minsWithZ = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    var secsWithZ = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
    var time = minsWithZ + ":" + secsWithZ;
    this.tempo_txt.text = time;

}   

pausa.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, menuPause);

function menuPause(e:MouseEvent){
    ...somegame code...
    voltar.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, play);
}

function play (e:MouseEvent){
    ...some game code

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two choices at least:

1-Andre's answer;

2-my answer:

```
import flash.events.Event;





var dt:int = 9000

var diff:Number=0;
var prevDiff:Number=0;
var currentTime:Number=0;



var t:uint=0;
var totseconds:int=0;
var minutes:int=0;
var seconds:int=0;
var minsWithZ;
var secsWithZ;

var running:Boolean=true;

var time;
this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, updateTimer);




function updateTimer(e:Event){
if(dt<1){dt=1;menuPause(null)}
trace(running);
totseconds= Math.floor(dt/1000);
minutes= Math.floor(totseconds/60);
seconds= Math.floor(totseconds%60);
minsWithZ = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
secsWithZ = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
time = minsWithZ + ":" + secsWithZ;

this.tempo_txt.text = time;





if(running){

t= getTimer()-diff-prevDiff;
dt=5000- t;


}else{
diff=getTimer()-currentTime;


}




}

pausa.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, menuPause);
voltar.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, reset);



function menuPause(e:Event){
running=false;
currentTime=getTimer();
prevDiff+=diff;

}

function menuPlay (e:Event){
running=true;

}


function reset(){

running=true;

prevDiff+=9000;



}
```

A little explaination on code:
     getTimer() returns the miliseconds from when you opened the app and

> You can't Pause "getTimer()"

but you can get the time that game is paused and subtract from getTimer().
variable "diff" does that here.
and "currentTime" is when you paused the game.

Andre's answer is more easy;
my   answer   is  more **accurate**.

because getTimer() returns real miliseconds but timer is not ticking exactly accurate.ENTER_FRAME event and setInterval are also same as timer.

that means if you want a more simple code, use Andre's  and if you want an accurate Timer, use Mine.

and removing eventListener (3vilguy's answer) is not enough
because getTimer won't Pause !

I hope my answer be useful.

Comment: is it normal that the clock strarts at 8 seconds?

Comment: the clock doesn't start at 8.it start at about 9 and because you used 'Math.floor()',even if it is 8.99 it is floored to 8.that wasn't normal if it started from nine!

Comment: I was going to delete the comment because I understood right away the stupid question hahah sorry

Comment: But I have another question. If I want to make a gameover and then a play again, how can I "reset" the clock? I tried to remove the eventListner and then add it again but it's not working

Comment: It's not working perfectly :/ the don't starts at 9 seconds sometimes it strarts at 12 or 13

Comment: @HITMAN: I dont love your way make concurrence. But Your answer and Ines try have the problem, that ENTER_FRAME is called 25 times or whatever a second to show a count which changes only every second. No idea, why you think your answer is more accurate. It is harder for the processor. Your way to program "accurately" is one of the reasons because of people now dont trust in this technology: Overhead. And hot processors.

Comment: that shows every second because we convert miliseconds to seconds here. and Yes. it's harder for processor.BUT,it shows REAL time.timer class, setInterval() or enterFrame, are not showing real time. their time, has a delay. if you test them with a chronometer, you see that the time from the timer, is less than chronometer's.so if we want a timer or chronometer app ,we can't use timer class or other.we should use my code.but if we don't want full accuracy like here, we don't need trouble with my code.we use timer.

Answer (score 0):

Better using the `Timer`- Object

```
var seconds=9;
var t:Timer=new Timer(1000,seconds);

t.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, updateTimer);
t.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, timerCompleteHandler);
updateTimer();    
t.start();
function updateTimer(e:TimerEvent=null){
    var t:uint = t.currentCount;
    var dt:uint = seconds - t;
    var totseconds:uint = dt;
    var minutes:uint = Math.floor(totseconds/60);
    var sec:uint = Math.floor(totseconds%60);
    var minsWithZ = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    var secsWithZ = sec < 10 ? "0" + sec : sec;
    var time = minsWithZ + ":" + secsWithZ;
    this.tempo_txt.text = time;

}   
function timerCompleteHandler(e:TimerEvent):void{
    trace("Timer complete");
}

pausa.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, menuPause);

function menuPause(e:MouseEvent){
   t.stop();
    voltar.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, play);
}

function play (e:MouseEvent){
    t.start();

}
```

Greetings

Comment: That ^      or just this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, updateTimer); in menuPause function.

Comment: yes it works! thanks. But the clock only appears one second after I open the game, I suppose because of this      var t:Timer=new Timer(1000,seconds);

Comment: I changed it in the code above. Needed to call `timerUpdate` at first indepent of the timeEvent. SRY for my engish.

Comment: @3vilguy: Only doing like your answer suggest, will it work, because in the original function the deltaTime is computed by the `getTimer()`-method. Doing in your way would need to save a class var to save the deltatime. But generally ENTER_FRAME is not the smartest solve for this problem.

Comment: @AndreLehnert correct. If you were about to remove ENTER_FRAME event you need extra variable so you can resume.